# Redirect keyboards input to an other process using java

Tags: java, javafx, process, stdin

I have a simple javaFX application using fxml files with SceneBuilder. Right now I am trying to launch a `notepad++` process from java then redirect keyboard input from the current active view to the `notepad++` process.

Basically I would write from my javaFX app indirectly to `notepadd++`

Here's my code so far trying with BufferedWriter:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("notepad++.exe");
Process p = pb.start();
InputStream stdin= p.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter keyboardInput_writer = new BufferedWriter(new OuputStreamWriter(stdin));

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
  if (sc.hasNext()) {
    try {
      keyboardInput.write(sc.nextLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error while capturing keyboard bytes stream.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

notepad++ is opening well, but when I get back on the javaFX active window and try to enter some keyboard keys the process freeze. I guess I should redirect the keys as bytes instead of text but which classes should I use to redirect keyboard keys to a java process object?

**EDIT:** What I really want to know is that if it is possible to send keyboard event data (like KeyCode integers) to a subprocess java (like notepad++) using the subprocess stdin.

If yes which java librairies to use?